# Oh dear, I've got my puzzle all stuck to itself, please help!

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

Oh dear.

It seems I've got myself in a spot of *extremely circumstantial and convoluted* bother again.

I was building this quick puzzle for a Fun Friday session, but I seem to have got the ends stuck to each other. I can't even remember where the start was.

[image]

If anybody can help me solve this, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Cute puzzle - it was fun to break into, and it had a nice self-confirming mechanism!

Comment: It may help to specify that it's the director of the original film (I wasn't aware of it and the top search result was the more recent film by that title which turns out to be a remake)

Comment: your dashes are hard to tell apart... so close together!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe the clues and blanks are filled out like this:

> Slapstick duo, **Laurel** and who?: **HARDY**
>  The **Hardy** boyz theme name. : [**LOADED**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardy_Boyz)
>  **Loaded** ones of these will never lose. : **DICE**
>  Driving too fast is to **dice** with who? : **DEATH**
>  Film director of "**Death** Wish". [**WINNER**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071402/)
>  Wreath given to ancient **winner**s: [**LAUREL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_wreath)

Comment: damn! I was writting this, couldn't figure out "dice" though

Comment: Absolutely perfect, and the links you've given are really great for the slightly less common-knowledge parts.

Comment: Being non-native speaker, the too fast - dice connection did not make sense to me. Googling around found an article such as this to explain the wording: https://thewest.com.au/opinion/editorials/too-many-dice-with-death-and-pay-penalties-with-their-lives-ng-b88344124z

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen That's something I hadn't considered. I'll definitely put some thought into appropriate use of english idioms in future.

Comment: @Bilkokuya I think the idiom to dice with death is common enough that I wouldn't worry about it. A quick ngram search shows it has been around since the 1800s

Comment: clearly you haven't found which one was the start, though, since your last one connects to your first one.